# Django foreign key count queries

Tags: django, django-models

I have models `A` and `B` that are like this:

```
class B(models.Model):
    x_count = models.IntegerField()
    y_count = models.IntegerField()

class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

I am trying to query out all instances of `A` that has `b` in which the total of `x_count` and `y_count` is zero. Something like

`SELECT A.name FROM A, B WHERE A.b = B.id AND B.x_count + B.y_count > 0`. How can I do that in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model may help.

You can use those to "compare the value of a model field with another field on the same model."

So your query might look like this (untested)

```
from django.db.models import F
A.objects.filter(x_count=-F('y_count'))
```